# Flutter: custom model returning null "List<dynamic> is not a subtype of List<String>" | "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Product'"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am calling a function that returns a future of custom model `Products` from `Futurebuilder`, and I am getting an error saying:

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Product'
```

This is my `Product` model:

```java
class Product {
  @required
  final String? id;
  @required
  final String? title;
  @required
  final String? discription;
  @required
  final double? price;
  @required
  final List<String>? info;
  @required
  final List<String>? imageUrl;
  final String? category;
  final offPerCent;

  final String? seller;
  Product({
    this.id,
    this.discription,
    this.info,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.price,
    this.seller,
    this.title,
    this.category,
    this.offPerCent
  });
}
```

And this is the function:

```java
Future<Product> getbyId(String id) async {
  var snapshot =
    await firestore.collection('products').where('id', isEqualTo: id).get();
  Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.docs[0].data();
  return new Product(
    id: data['id'],
    title: data['title'],
    price: data['price'],
    seller: data['seller'],
    category: data['category'],
    discription: data['discription'],
    imageUrl: data['imageUrl'],
    info: data['info'],
    offPerCent: data['offPerCent'],
  );
}
```

I think there is some problem with the info and imageUrl field, both them are `List<String>` when I comment on both that line everything works fine.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Which line of code is that error referring to? It means that you are trying to put a Null in a Product reference as in `p = null`. The line that the error points to will help understand the problem better.

Comment: the problem is while returning the model 'Product" only if am assigning the value for the info and imageurl field. now I changed the code to ```info: List<String>.from(data['info'])``` and it is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
info: List<String>.from(data['info'])
```

Do the same for image.

Explanation:
The error that happened which displayed a message saying `product is null`, is actually caused by another error.
This error arises while creating your product object. And it happens in the fields mentioned above, where you specified a `List<String>` will come from Firebase. But Firebase SDK lists objects as `List<dynamic>`.

So probably there was another error in debug console saying

```
List<dynamic> is not a subtype of List<String> as in cast.
```

When you tell it to create a List from the elements inside the List, it works well, as long as those elements are actually strings. If you go to firebase, and change any of the items into anything besides string, you'll have another error saying `int is not a subtype of type string` for example.

Because creating a `Product` object from the map returned from firebase, goes through the steps in your method `fromMap()` in the model, it stops when it hits the error explained above, and therefore a product object never finishes creating it from a map.

Then, the widget waiting for the `Product` object to be returned, never receives what it was waiting for, you get the error in your original question.

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Product'
```

You can avoid the third scenario, to account for anything coming from firebase, which is not a string, for example someone inputs an integer or double or null, by doing this:

```
info: List<String>.from(data['info'].map((element)=> element.toString()).toList());
```

This is an example:

```
List a = ['a', 1, '2', null]; //this is List<dynamic>
// List<String> b = List<String>.from(a); //This will give you an error when it encounters the number 1, it won't even continue.

List<String> b = List<String>.from(a.map((element) => element.toString()).toList()); 
print(b); // prints this => [a, 1, 2, null]

//because all the elements inside were converted to a string first.
```

Comment: thanks! this worked for me, can you please explain what went wrong there?

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer, because it didn't fit here, and for better formatting. You're most welcome :)